# How to convert IEnumerable<CustomType> to List, applying grouping logic, and convert back to IEnumerable<CustomType>?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to take a list of items from a table, apply grouping logic(grouping by assignment type, start and end time), and then convert back to starting type.

```
  IEnumerable<Assignment> assignments = UnitOfWork.AssignmentRepository.Get(filter: a => a.Start.CompareTo(start) >= 0
                    && a.End.CompareTo(end) <= 0,
                    orderBy: o => o.OrderBy(a => a.Start));

    List<Assignment> pre_alerts = new List<Assignment>();

 foreach (Assignment a in assignments)
            {
                foreach (AssignmentType t in assignmentTypes)
                {  // determine if the assignment's type has a minimum required
                    if (a.AssignmentTypeID == t.AssignmentTypeID && t.Minimum>0)
                    {

                        // get the minimum assignments requierd
                        int min_required = t.Minimum;

                        DateTime s = a.Start;
                        DateTime e = a.End;
                        AssignmentType type = a.AssignmentType;

                        IEnumerable<Assignment> minimum_assignments = UnitOfWork.AssignmentRepository.Get(filter: m => m.Start.CompareTo(s) >= 0 && m.End.CompareTo(e) <= 0 && m.AssignmentTypeID == a.AssignmentTypeID, orderBy: o => o.OrderBy(m => m.Start));

                        int min_actual = minimum_assignments.Count();

                        if (min_actual < min_required)
                        { 
                        // add a single alert for time range and assignment type
                           pre_alerts.Add(a);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
 var alerts = pre_alerts.GroupBy(x => new Assignment{ x.AssignmentTypeID, x.Start, x.End }).Select(k => k);
```

how do I convert alerts to `IEnumerable<Assignment>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Select` you are already returning it as an IEnumerable. If you want it to be of your type then:

```
var alerts = pre_alerts.GroupBy(x => new Assignment{ x.AssignmentTypeID, x.Start, x.End }).Select(k => k.Key);
```

The result of a `GroupBy` is an `IGrouping` so by Selecting just `k` you are returning an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<Assignment...>>`

But it feels to me that if that is the case then there is no reason to use the `GroupBy` but just `Select` to create the assignments and then distinct

Comment: how would I do that without the groupby?

Comment: @user5120455 - what is exactly is the logic you want? It seems like you are doing aggregation logic that you can do in linq. If you replace what you have with `.Where`s for the `if` statements. Specifically about the group by - why did you decide to do it?